# Correction of heteroskedasticity in random effect models in panel data

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, inference, panel-data, random-effects-model

Considering that random effects use GLS estimators, which are used to correct heteroscedasticity, is it necessary to worry about correcting such problem in a random effects model or not, is it necessary to correct such problem?

Answer (score 0):

GLS estimators are simply the MLEs under the model with heteroscedastic variance components.  Likewise, for a random effects model one formulates the model's likelihood and obtains the MLEs of all of its parameters.  In this case a profiling argument reveals that MLEs of the fixed effects are GLS estimators since the random effects model only adds variance components.  If one does not use the correct estimator or appropriate modelling assumptions, one is unable to correctly quantify the uncertainty in the estimator, hence your prediction bounds and confidence bounds will be misleading.